# Как создать JSON в javascript?

Tags: javascript

Надо создать документ такого вида

```
{
"menu0":{"title":"Для нее","id":57,"cat":1},
"menu1":{"title":"Для дома","id":62, "cat":1},
}
```

Пытаюсь создать так

```
$("#secure").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var menu
    $( "#sortable li" ).each(function (i) {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var cat = $(this).data('cat');
        var title=$(this).data('title');
        //var menu={title: title, id: id, cat: cat };
       var addmenu ={menu:menu}
        console.log(JSON.stringify(addmenu));
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(menu));
});
```

Получаю

```
{"menu":{"title":"Для нее","id":57,"cat":1}}
{"menu":{"title":"Для дома","id":62,"cat":1}}
```

Как правильно – не понимаю.

Comment: правильно, надо имя давать названию свойства

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы печатаете строку вместо того, чтоб добавлять ее в массив/объект. Объявите отдельную переменную для всего содержания "документа", отдельную переменную для одного элемента. Например, так:

```
var menu = {};
$( "#sortable li" ).each(function (i) {
    // ...
    var key = 'menu' + i;
    var addmenu = {title: title, id: id, cat: cat };
    menu[key] = addmenu;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(menu));
```

И избегайте не инициализированных переменных - таких, как menu в вашем примере. Если селектор не вернет ни одного li, то переменная так и останется не инициализированной (вы увидите undefined или ошибку).

Comment: И если вы хотите получить валидный JSON, то запятая после последнего элемента не нужна. Да и удобнее будет хранить всё в обычном массиве, а не в объекте.

Comment: _Первый аргумент анонимной функции не будет содержать индекс элемента - надо подсчитать его вручную._ - почему не будет? Вы знаете что-то чего нет в документации? [.each( function )
function
Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function)

Comment: Извиняюсь, перепутал. Исправил в ответе

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае идет отображение коллекции элементов на массив объектов, и последующая свертка массива в объект, если обратить внимание на имена ключей можно заметить, что они соответствуют индексам с префиксом *menu*.

Для отображения одной коллекции в другую используется [метод map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) с последующим вызовом [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/), для получения массива, а не объекта jQuery.

Массив нужен, так как, в объекте jQuery отсутствует [метод *reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), который будет использоваться для сворачивания в объект.

Код в итоге может выглядеть так:

```
var menu = $( "#sortable li" ).map((i, el)=> {
    id: $(el).data('id'),
    title: $(el).data('title'),
    cat: $(el).data('cat')
})
.get()
.reduce((resultObj, cur, i)=> {
    resultObj[`menu${i}`] = cur;
    return resultObj;
}, {});
```